# Foreach para crear elementos de lista en HTML

Tags: php, html

Mi consulta es la siguiente: De qué forma puedo ir creando una lista al hacer el foreach para q se vaya agregando elementos en la lista, como por ejemplo se hace en una datatable.

Gracias, de ante mano, por si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
    <?php if (isset($movimiento)) { ?>
    
           <?php foreach ($movimiento as $data) { ?>
                                        
                         <?php if($data['fecha_hora_movimiento']!=NULL){
                            $fecha_hora_movimiento = date("d/m/Y - H:i:s",  strtotime($data['fecha_hora_movimiento']));
                            echo $fecha_hora_movimiento;}?>
                      <?php if($data['tipo_movimiento']!=NULL){echo $data['tipo_movimiento'];}?>
                            <?php  echo $data['area']; ?>
                                <?php  echo $data['area']; ?>   
                                                    
                                <?php } ?>
                         <?php } ?>
                                          
                                                <ol class="activity-feed mb-0">
                                                    <li class="feed-item">
                                                        <div class="feed-item-list">
                                                            <p class="text-muted mb-1">18/09/2020</p>
                                                            <h5>
                                                                <p class="font-15 mt-0 mb-0">Estado: <span
                                                                        class="badge badge-success">Iniciado</span></p>
                                                            </h5>
                                                            <p class="font-8 mt-0 mb-0">Area entrante:<b class="text-success">
                                                                    SEM</b>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <p class="font-8 mt-0 mb-0">Area saliente:<b class="text-danger">
                                                                    Ambiente y
                                                                    servicio</b></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ol>
    
    
                                            <?php } ?>
    
                                        <?php } ?>
```

Quiero ***lograr*** algo como esto, pero no sé como recorrer un array y tampoco sé cómo vienen los datos para ser recorridos.

Quiero que aparezcan los estados, area y fecha como en la siguiente imágen:

[image: JEMPLO].

Comment: lo mas importante es saver como vienen los datos... si no sabes como vienen los datos tendras que hacer debug del contenido e ir tanteando donde esta cada cosa que necesitas y validar que siempre exista ese nodo/dato...

Comment: en cuanto a lo que quieres hacer... para que lusca ta cual es cuestion de diseño css y de evaluar la informacion y aplicarle el CSS en el backend que corresponda con la evaluacion del dato por ejemplo: iniciado == verde; Finalizado == rojo... con evaluaciones logicas que debes hacer dentro del bucle ... no es tan dificil ... simplemente es pensar, aplicar logica y escribir el codigo....

Comment: por otro lado no veo ningun error en particular, si existe algun error por favor indica cual es para ver si te podemos ayudar... cuanto a lo demas esta basado en opiniones ...

Answer (score -1):

Tienes muy bien la lógica, entiendo lo que quieres hacer porque ya he analizado un código que funciona con algo parecido a esto.
Lo que debes hacer es crear condiciones para saber qué datos están siendo tratados en x tiempo específico, y traer esa data y dibujarla con el DOM y JavaScript.

Para esto necesitarás estos conocimientos:

1. Peticiones a **APIs REST** con JavaScript o PHP
2. Conocimientos sobre el **DOM de HTML** para dibujar cada uno de los estados
3. **FPDF** para manejar la generación de archivos PDF a través de tu aplicación
4. Sintaxis de PHP o JavaScript

Ahora bien, para crear un foreach en PHP es bien simple, es como lo has hecho hasta ahora, aunque no veo dónde tienes el arreglo o los datos que estas ciclando.

Te daré un ejemplo sencillo para que vallas avanzando:

```
<?php
/* Creamos un arreglo que tendrá los datos o hacemos una petición que generará este arreglo*/
    $empleados = array(
                array("nombre"=>"Raúl", "apellido"=>"Molina"),
                array("nombre"=>"Víctor", "apellido"=>"Gómez"),
                array("nombre"=>"Amelia", "apellido"=>"Vega"),
                array("nombre"=>"Alicia", "apellido"=>"Ortega"),
                );
?>

<?php
// Recorremos el arreglo
foreach ($empleados as $cols) {
    echo "<ul>";    
        echo "<li>".$cols["nombre"]."</li>";
        echo "<li>".$cols["apellido"]."</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}

?>
```

Así es como se utiliza un foreach para recorrer un arreglo, otras cosas que te pueden interesar para hacer lo que necesitas es la función array_push(), y json_encode().

Sin más, me despido.
Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: En objetivo es hacer un registro de activiadades recientes . desplazando como en la lista de acuerdo a su estado

Comment: Con la información que te acabo de dar puedes hacer lo que quieres. Ya he visto como lo han hecho anteriormente y solamente usan esos puntos que te he comentado.